# Problems in adjusting rate/pitch in Alexa SSML

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, ssml

I was trying to adjust Alexa talking speed and pitch with following:

```
outputSpeech: {
            type: "SSML",
            ssml: "<speak><prosody pitch="+50%">higher pitch</prosody></speak>"
},
```

The execution result succeeded, however I noticed `"ssml": "<speak><prosody pitch=NaN"`
and when I went to simulator test, Alexa responded `There was a problem with the requested skill's response`

So I tried couple things:

```
ssml: "<speak><prosody rate="150%">faster pace</prosody></speak>"
```

the execution result fails:
    "SyntaxError: Unexpected number",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try escaping the double quotes inside **prosody** tag attributes using this \"

```
"<speak><prosody pitch=\"+50%\">higher pitch</prosody></speak>"
```

or use a single quote

```
  const speechOutput = '<speak><prosody pitch="+50%">higher pitch</prosody></speak>';
      return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(speechOutput)
      .getResponse();
```